# control not returned to main thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written a python program in which I created a UDP listener in thread 1 and trying to do something in thread 2. The issue here is control is stuck up in thread 1 and it never returns to main thread so thread 2 is not even starting up.

```
import threading
import socket
import time

data = ''

def ListenerUDP():
    sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_address1 = ('localhost', 5000)
    print('starting up UDP server on %s port %s' % server_address1)
    sock1.bind(server_address1)

    while True:
        print('\nUDP server is now listening up')
        data, address = sock1.recvfrom(4096)
        print('received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
        print('is %s' % data.hex())


def Forwarder():
    print('do something')


print('Starting main thread')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=ListenerUDP)
t1.start()

t2 = threading.Thread(target=Forwarder)
t2.start()
```

can someone please help fixing it.

Comment: I think the sock1.recvfrom(4096) is a blocking call .. Thread gets stuck at that point and does not let go of GIL

Comment: On second look ... Its fine .. it's just that your `print('do something')` is not in the loop so it only runs once and stops

Comment: Thanks, Strangely it started working now. Not sure how.